# creating an instance variable by using class name doesn't work out of Main method

Tags: c#

Guys when I try to create an instance variable to create an istance of class (object) out of Main method it doesn't work. I couldn't understand why ? I have really searched on the Internet many times.

For example

[This works](https://i.stack.imgur.com/prwhS.png)

[This doesn't work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NsCxg.png)

As I learned before keywords "int", "string" etc. are kind of class. I can create a instance variable by using those keywords (i.e class) out of Main() method.

But Why I cant create an istance variable  by using class name out of Main() method.

My second question is  I  am really wondering why do I need a instance variable by using class name.

I mean when I create an istance variable by using "string", "int" etc. keywords. I can picture thpe of that variable. But when ı created a instance variable by using class name I can't picture anything in my mind.

Thanks advance for your interest

Comment: That's because you've declared your method as a [Static method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/static-classes-and-static-class-members).

Comment: Please note that code should be included as text in your question, not as images. There are a number of reasons, the main one being that we can't debug images. Next, "doesn't work" is not descriptive of a problem. I'd go so far as to say that "doesn't work" is the default condition on this website - why would you be posting here if your code was working perfectly? Please be specific: if you're getting an error message, give us the error message. If your code is misbehaving, tell us how it is misbehaving and what it should be doing.

Comment: @John Sorry. I'm gonna keep in mind your advice . I wıll be more careful when I ask a new question. Thank you for enlightening me .

Comment: @Progman I will analyze  and reanswer. Thanks for your interest

Comment: I wrote the  the code to C#  which was asked  by owner but didn't work in C#. So my question is still continue @Progman

Comment: @AlpayPalabıyık Please [edit] your question to include the full source code you have and the full error message/exception you get. Please see: [What Do You Mean “It Doesn't Work”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/147616)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For your second question, in C#, an instance of a class is always a [reference variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/reference-types). (I recommend you to read more about it in the internet). Therefore, in the example:

```
class Student
{
   Student st1;
}
```

`str1` can reference to an area in the RAM. You can picture it as an arrow to a rectangle. The arrow is the variable that reference to the rectangle, which is the place on the RAM. By creating an instance of a class inside of the class itself, we actually create an arrow to a new rectangle that has also an arrow that can reference to a rectangle too, and so on.

It is useful, for example, to create a list of nodes. Each node references to another node, like the following:

```
class Node
{
   public int number;
   public Node next; // Here we create a new arrow to a new rectangle, which has an arrow too
}
```

And in the `Main` method:

```
Node first = new Node();
first.number = 1;

Node second = new Node();
second.number = 2;

first.next = second; // Here we "match" the arrow to a rectangle. The arrow is "first.next", and the rectangle is "second".

Node third = new Node();
third.number = 3;

second.next = third;

// We have a list: 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> null
// The end of the list is null, becuase third.next references to null (it references to no "rectangle")
```

We can do it in a different way:

```
Node first = new Node();
first.number = 1;

first.next = new Node();
first.next.number = 2;

first.next.next = new Node();
first.next.next.number = 3;

// In this way, we have only the "head" of the list ("first"), but we can get any node that in the list by typing "first.next. ....... .next"

// We can also iterate over the list:
Node p = first;
while (p != null) // while we are not in the end of the list
{
   // Do something, like "Console.WriteLine(p.number);" or "p.number++;"
   p = p.next; // We go to the next node
}
```

It is useful, because this list has no limited length and we can add nodes and remove nodes easily.

For example:

```
public class Program
{
     public static void Main(string[] args)
     {
          Node first = new Node();
          int counter = 0;
         
          first.number = counter;
          counter++;
         
          // Inialize a list of 10 nodes:
          Node p = first; // We don't want to lost the "head" of our list, "first"
          while (counter < 10)
          {                
              p.next = new Node(); // We create a new node
              p.next.number = counter; // And we initialize it
              
              counter++;
              p = p.next; // We go to the next node
          }
          
          // Now we print all the number in our list:
          p = first; // We don't want to lost the "head" of our list, "first"
          while (p != null)
          {
              Console.WriteLine(p.number);
              p = p.next; // We go to the next node
          }
     }
}
```

Output:

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```

Hope it will be helpful!

Comment: Thanks for your interest @Avi. But It's not what I asked. I asked like :

class Student
{
   Student st1;
}
This is what I am asking. Where do we use this "st1" variable. Actually what is "st1" variable ?

Comment: @AlpayPalabıyık, sorry for not understand you. I edited my answer. Hope it will be useful!

Comment: Thank you very much really. It helped a lot. That what I was asking. Thanks really a lot